# Getting HTML tag in mobile browser by switmailor

Tags: php, html, swiftmailer

We have made a form and we are sending its data on email using swiftmailor library.

If user fill data from desktop browser than the data is shown in correct format without HTML tags but if user fill data from mobile browser than htMl tags are coming in email .

Can you suggest if it is problem of mobile browser or swiftmailor.

We are using header :

```
$headers = "From: " . 'XYZ' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

and sending mail by swiftmailor

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Enquiry FORM')
->setFrom(array('noreply@XYZ.com' => 'XYZ'))   
->setTo(array($sendTo))
->setBody($messageContent, 'text/html')  ;

  // Send the message
   $result = $mailer->send($message);
```

Please suggest what solution should be implemented so that both browser can send html format.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
setBody($this->renderView($messageContent), 'text/html');
```

instead of this

```
setBody($messageContent, 'text/html')  ;
```

Comment: It does not work Abdulla, Do you have any another solution ?